# JSON loop through key value pairs to set another key value

Tags: json, loops, key-value

I'm very new to scripting and JSON and I'm trying to loop through some key pairs in an object (shown below) to accomplish, "if the value in 3[x].4 = 'BBB', then return the value in 3[x].1"

Happy to elaborate on this as I know this may not be clear. Thank you in advance for any help!

```
var pID = {
'3[1].1': '111111',
'3[1].4': 'PPP',
'3[1].5': 'PPP',
'3[2].1': '222222',
'3[2].4': 'MMM',
'3[2].5': 'MMM',
'3[3].1': '333333',
'3[3].4': 'BBB',
'3[3].5': 'BBB',
'3[4].1': '444444',
'3[4].4': 'XXX',
'3[4].5': 'XXX'}
```

Comment: Hey @Brendan, are the values always in sorted order? In terms of the 1 4 5 pattern?

Comment: Yes, they'll always be in that order.

Answer (score 0):

Since JS objects are (by definition) an unsorted set of key-value pairs, it would not make sense to use to order to get the results we are looking for.

With this solution you will need to figure out the value for `i < 4` somehow. Not sure what the best way would be with this limited context. One solution could be `Math.ceil(Object.keys(pID).length / 3)`

```
var pID = {
    '3[1].1': '111111',
    '3[1].4': 'PPP',
    '3[1].5': 'PPP',
    '3[2].1': '222222',
    '3[2].4': 'MMM',
    '3[2].5': 'MMM',
    '3[3].1': '333333',
    '3[3].4': 'BBB',
    '3[3].5': 'BBB',
    '3[4].1': '444444',
    '3[4].4': 'XXX',
    '3[4].5': 'XXX',
};

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    let currentKey = `3[${i}].4`;
    if (currentKey in pID) {
        let currentValue = pID[currentKey];
        if ((currentValue == 'BBB')) console.log(pID[`3[${i}].1`]);
    }
}
```